# How to serve customized webpages?

Tags: php, subdomain, customization

We have a basic service that some people use but most people want their "own" as in custom solutions to their needs.  We are planning that now, so i wanted to have a great conversation with our community about it:

What would be the best way to serve custom pages designed for individual clients.  Like do a php redirect to their page via session authentication or hard write the same website but with their needs in mind?

So for example:  Everybody who wants the existing solution go to www.domain.com and sign in.  But those who want customizations as in features, analytical tools, can login to a subdomain created by us an then including the features they need.

So its either we do PHP redirects and have everybody under that one system or if they required customizations, we physically create subdomains and serve those needs?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if I am too tired but this makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: it doesn't make sense because the suggested solutions are arse backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just store their preferences in a database, and render the page based on their preferences?

this way you write one script, you can add modules at any time for any user without rewriting anything. they could even customize the features of their page through a preferences form.

Comment: I get the gist of it but don't full understand you.  Can you put it into an example.  To give you an idea of what we are doing is this:  Think Facebook. Everybody gets their own accounts.  But you decide that you want a feature that is unique to you, like analyze how many friends you have and tell you how is the closest, for example.  So how would we show that to you.. thats why i was thinking subdomains.

Comment: @AAA do you know PHP? do you know MySQL? users would create accounts via a form. submitting the form would create an account for them in your database. you could then link preferences to their account. PHP would then print different things, depening on what is in their database record....... i mean this is days of coding. i can't make it for you.

Comment: hey thanks.  i got your point.  wasn't thinking straight. well thanks for saving me days of work worrying about hard coding subdomains website...

Comment: Just one further question>  i can store code in the mysql db and then serve it?

Comment: You could, but then you would have to eval it when you pull it from the database which is bad, and it would bog down your database, and should not be necessary. You will want a user record table, and a preferences table that is linked to the user table by id. when you get to the spot of your page where a particular module should be printed to screen, you would check the prefences table of the database to see if that user has that module enabled, and if they do, print the module, otherwise, don't.

Comment: How do i load those preferences/classes/modules.... i asked that question here:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479804/how-to-load-variations-of-a-code-based-on-user

Comment: ehhh... hire a programmer... if you don't understand anything it will take a lonnnnnnnnng time to learn enough to do this.

Comment: come on man give me a shot.  just give me a gist of it... please!

Comment: Is this the right way:    http://www.vbadvanced.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-12741.html