# How to load variations of a code based on user?

Tags: php, customization

I want to be able to server different variations of a code based on the user.  So if USer A signs in i want them to see code/pages pertaining to their preferences.

I know we can do a php/mysql to save paths.  But how do i serve the code on the same page.  All users have the same page index.php, home.php, profile.php but i want to be able to use the same page to serve those requests by simply show the code that is specifc to them..

Answer (score 1):

Just a try...

You can store the preferences loaded from your database or what so ever, in session variables.
Next step is to simply print those variables on the page. This way every user gets its own page.

Example:

```
echo "<p>Welcome ".$_SESSION['username']." to your domain!</p><br />";  
echo "<p>I heard you like ".$_SESSION['fav_food']." a lot.</p>";
```

This will put out:

```
Welcome Barney to you domain!  
I head you like chocolate coockies a lot.
```

You could also try to use Ajax, but I'm a noob in Ajax myself so I can't help you with that, but you could do some searching.

I hope it can help you!

**UPDATE:**

To set a session variable you can load a value from what ever your source is and store it like any other variable.
Like:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $queryresult['user'];
```

Make sure you enabled the session by starting each page with:

```
session_start();
```

I'll hope this is an answer to your question.

Where do you actually get the information of User a from? I suppose a database?

Comment: Not really familiar with Ajax.  How can i load custom code into this code? Like lets a custom feature.  How can i load it into the code you have submitted above..

Comment: This has nothing to do with AJAX, ignore that bit, but note the rest. Session data is most likely what you want here.

Comment: I get that part.  What i don't get is how to serve a customized code.  let says i designed a feature specifcally for you.  And you should be the one to see it.  So instead of redirecting you to a seperate page, how can i serve you that code on a page that everyone else gets as a member but the features and services are unique to you.

Comment: If you got 'features and services' unique for each member of your site, you should store those features and services in your database and load them when a user requests them. Make sure it is all uniform for example the profile page on stackoverflow. Moreover, if you could tell what kind of features you mean the answer on your question might be given more easily.

Comment: The feature could be another text field or something like a analytical tool or a photo enhancement feature

Comment: You can store the html code into your database. for example: If a user wants 3 textfields you can simply send <textarea style="your style">value</textarea> to the database. On loading the page you can check the database for html code and load it in.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're after, but maybe it'll help get you on the right path...

```
<?php
    // sample preferences, read from database
    $userPrefs = array(
        'block1' => true,
        'block2' => false,
        'block3' => true
    );

    $block1 = '<div id="block1">This is Block #1!</div>' . PHP_EOL;
    $block2 = '<div id="block2">This is Block #2!</div>' . PHP_EOL;
    $block3 = '<div id="block3">This is Block #3!</div>' . PHP_EOL;

    if ($userPrefs['block1'] == true) { echo $block1; }
    if ($userPrefs['block2'] == true) { echo $block2; }
    if ($userPrefs['block3'] == true) { echo $block3; }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<div id="block1">This is Block #1!</div>
<div id="block3">This is Block #3!</div>
```

Comment: Ok.  This might be it.  So I can include php code within the blocks an serve them.  Give me 24 hours to play with it.  Thanks!